# debugging segmentation fault when using `prin1`

Tags: debugging, backtrace

**Q**:  How can I narrow down this `gdb` backtrace to a specific character, or set of characters, that is causing a Emacs to suffer a segmentation fault when using `prin1`?

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000100141da7 in print_object (obj=4790542093, printcharfun=0, 
    escapeflag=true) at print.c:1350
1350    {
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x0000000100141da7 in print_object (obj=4790542093, printcharfun=0, 
    escapeflag=true) at print.c:1350
        buf = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\070\346\211\035\001", '\000' <repeats 11 times>, "\303o\024\034\001\000\000\000\350\345\211\035\001", '\000' <repeats 11 times>, "\320\360:_\377\177"
#1  0x000000010014261f in print_object (obj=4766068675, printcharfun=0, 
    escapeflag=true) at print.c:1659
        halftail = 4766068675
        print_length = 9223372036854775807
        i = 1
        buf = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\070\346\211\035\001", '\000' <repeats 11 times>, "\265މ\035\001\000\000\000\350\345\211\035\001", '\000' <repeats 11 times>, "`\363:_\377\177"
#2  0x0000000100143a77 in print_object (obj=<optimized out>, printcharfun=0, 
    escapeflag=true) at print.c:1965
        idx = 0
        tem = 4790542093
        size = 10
        buf = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\070\346\211\035\001", '\000' <repeats 11 times>, "\243#\n\034\001\000\000\000\350\345\211\035\001", '\000' <repeats 11 times>, "\360\365:_\377\177"
#3  0x000000010014261f in print_object (obj=4765393827, printcharfun=0, 
    escapeflag=true) at print.c:1659
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

Comment: I think `p obj` and then `xpr` should show you what's being printed.

Comment: @npostavs -- thank you.  I came up with a way to reproduce this error, and will spend some time working on it over the next few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@npostavs was able to track the problem down in the Emacs bug report 27571:  http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=27571

In a nutshell, the error is caused because the `ulimit` stack size is too low to handle this particular situation.  `ulimit -S -s unlimited` resolves this issue.

In the event the Emacs team implements a fix, or if another solution is found, I will update this answer.

I the meantime, I am starting the GUI version of Emacs with a bash script that first executes `ulimit -S -s unlimited` followed by the absolute path to the Emacs executable and the `&` symbol.

```
#!/bin/sh

ulimit -S -s unlimited

/path/to/emacs &
```